# ¿Cómo puedo evitar que un usuario logueado no regrese al login utilizando angular4?

Tags: javascript, login, angular, ngroute

Soy nuevo en Angular y me gustaría saber cual es la mejor opción o como puedo hacer para no mostrar la pantalla de **login** si el usuario esta **logueado**.

Estoy utilizando **canActivate** para proteger rutas y token en el localstorage.

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  redirectTo: '/login',
  pathMatch: 'full'
}, {
  path: 'login',
  component: LoginComponent
}, {
  path: 'home',
  component: HomeComponent,
  canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  children: [{
    path: 'usuarios',
    loadChildren: './users/users.module#UsersModule'
  }, {
    path: 'cua',
    loadChildren: './cua/cua.module#CuaModule'
  }]
}];
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el problema? Si dices que estás usando canActivate, puedes crear una regla inversa al resto: si el usuario está logueado e intenta ir a /login, lo rediriges a alguna otra pantalla.

Comment: Ok. Entiendo,  esa regla la haría en el constructor del componente o en el hook ngOnInit() o donde defino mis rutas?

Comment: No, me refería a un "guard" en el canActivate. Si dices que ya lo usas, añadir otro es trivial

Comment: const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  {
    path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], children: [
      { path: 'usuarios', loadChildren: './users/users.module#UsersModule' },
      { path: 'cua', loadChildren: './cua/cua.module#CuaModule' }
    ]
  }
];

Comment: Añade eso a tu pregunta, usa [edit]

Comment: Gracias, amigo. Buen día

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dices que ya usas canActivate en tu router para permitir o denegar el acceso, algo como lo siguiente:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private router: Router, private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        if (this.authenticationService.isAuthenticated()) {
            // logged in so return true
            return true;
        }

        // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
        this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
        return false;
    }
}
```

En ese caso, puedes hacer una regla al revés:

```
@Injectable()
export class NoAuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private router: Router, private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        if (!this.authenticationService.isAuthenticated()) {
            // Not logged
            return true;
        }
        // Aquí puedes redirigir a otro sitio
        return false;
    }
}
```